# How to install cuda10.1 on ubuntu20.04 in a custom location

Tags: 20.04, cuda

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Win10. Is there a way to install the cuda10.1 in a custom location (e.g. `d drive: /mnt/d`) instead of my system drive (`/usr/bin`)?

Comment: I just download the deb file from Intel, and unpack it where I want to.  Lately, the deb only contains other debs, so repeat (skipping the unwanted nvidia debs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but keep in mind that this will probably not work since GPU acceleration under WSL (it's not clear if you're running under it or a VM) is not officially supported yet. In case you're running under WSL, there's a [public preview](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl) available from nvidia, but it seems to only offer CUDA 11.

In case you still want to install version 10.1 in a different folder, you'll need to download the installer from [nvidia's site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-update2?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=runfilelocal):

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.1/Prod/local_installers/cuda_10.1.243_418.87.00_linux.run
```

And, from the installer's help page:

> --installpath=
> Install everything to the  directory. This flag sets the same values
> as the toolkitpath, samplespath, and librarypath options.

So you can set this flag to whatever path you want to when running the installer.